# Mysql Procedure error while executing it

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures

I am creating procedure which selects member_id in courser.member_id having more that 100000 records.
i had declared one variable i which stores one member id at time update it with next query.

can anyone resolve this..?
procedure is as follows:-

```
     DELIMITER // 
    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS Mock_test_1()  
    CREATE PROCEDURE Mock_test_1()    
    BEGIN DECLARE i int unsigned;  
    DECLARE curs1 CURSOR FOR select member_id from client_master; 
    open curs1 read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH curs1 INTO i; 
    update client_master set `mobileno`='0000001231',`email`=concat('MOCK',member_id,'@mock.com'),`password`=md5('MOCK'),;
  END //
 DELIMITER ;
```

Error

> > ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
> >     syntax to use near '()  CREATE PROCEDURE Mock_test_1()    BEGIN
>
> DECLARE i int unsigned;
>
> DECLARE cu' at line 1

Comment: add a `;` after `DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS Mock_test_1()  `

Comment: You have to change delimiter before using triggers, stored procedures and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change delimiter before using triggers, stored procedures and so on.

Comment: he has changed the delimiter so he is ok

Comment: problem is at the semicolon at drop procedure

Comment: i had maid changes but its giving some error

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS Mock_test_1;
CREATE PROCEDURE Mock_test_1()
   BEGIN
DECLARE i int unsigned;
DECLARE curs1 CURSOR FOR select member_id from client_master;
open curs1;
read_loop: LOOP
      FETCH curs1 INTO i;
update client_master set `mobileno`='01231',`email`=concat('MOCK',member_id,'@mock.com'),`password`=md5('MOCK'), businessaddress = concat('MOCK',member_id), imeino = '00000', panno= 'AAAAA66666' ,aadharno = '11111';
insert into client_master_test select * from client_master;
   END //
 DELIMITER ;